# IP Camera Android Application

Tags: java, android

I am new in android application
& I want to make android application to view & control IP cameras
but I don't know from where I can start
I want to know if there are specific cameras that can be controlled? or any IP camera can be controlled? 
as I want to choose between three types of VIVOTEK camera
please any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This may work --> http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

But I suppose this is for Camera View in the web view ( in the browser)
rgds
Softy